How do I edit "Open With" menu to remove duplicated items (macOS 14)

The problem is my Edge has upgraded from 80 to 97, so the answer here How do I remove specific items from my "Open With..." menu in High Sierra?, open the app to edit Info.plist won't work for me.
There is also the item Chromium that I have no idea at all where it comes from.
So how do I remove them ?
PS, I feel this old Q&A How do I remove duplicate "Open With" context menu items in Finder.app? won't work for me too.
--- update ---
I did not get an answer back then, and now it is a mess. So I am asking the question again.


Those apps are somewhere on your system. Possible on external drives.

You could try rebuilding the LaunchServices database.

Yeah as @benwiggy says, it sounds like rebuilding the LaunchServices database would be the cure. This blog post about LaunchServices issues and how to fix it is well worth reading! It explains the commands you need to run to rebuild it for you. https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/

It feels rather complicated and I dare to say I am not the one hits this problem. So I am hoping there could be some easier solution.

What happens when you select, for example, "Chromium"? Does an app open? Is it Chromium?

Chromium starts then quits without any message.

This doesn't appear to be an issue with the "Open With" menu but instead with you having multiple instances of the same app with different versions, which can be seen in your screenshots above (e.g., 130.0.2849.80, 130.0.2849.68, and 130.0.2849.56).
You can find all instances of the Microsoft Edge application via the Terminal application. There are a few ways you can access the Terminal application. Choose whichever of the following is most comfortable for you.

Search and open Terminal via spotlight search.


Go to /Applications/Utilities and open Terminal.app


Open Launchpad, go to the Other folder, and open Terminal.



Once you have opened the Terminal app, you can find all paths to the Microsoft Edge applications on your system by copying and pasting the following command into the Terminal application and hitting enter:
sudo find / -type d -name "Microsoft Edge.app" -print 2>/dev/null

Since this command requires administrator permissions, you will be prompted to enter a password (your login password). When typing your password, the letters, numbers, etc., that you type in will be invisible. So, don't worry if there does not seem to be any indication of a password being entered.
After inputting your password, you can hit the enter key. You will get a list of paths to all of the Microsoft Edge applications. If you want to go to any of these paths in Finder, you can go to finder and enter Command (⌘) + Shift (⇧) + G to pull up a prompt to go to a path.


@Qiulang邱朗 Ah, did only one showed up in Terminal when you executed the command? If you haven't yet, please try running the above steps. It is possible that there are multiple instances of Edge outside of the /Applications directory (e.g. ~/Library/Application Support).

No I just have ONE edge in application. I think it is because edge keep upgrade itself. I will open a issue against edge.

You are right!. This is definitely a bug for edge.

@Qiulang邱朗 Very possible. Also, if the paths show multiple instances of Edge with multiple version folders, you likely can delete the old version folders to remove the old instances of Edge as a temporary measure while you report this to Edge.

Did you know why that happened ?

@Qiulang邱朗 No. There are a few options, though. (1) Edge stores old versions of Edge as backups, which unfortunately show up in the "Open With" menu. (2) There is a bug with Edge being unable to or failing to delete old versions. (3) You have some unusual added folder to something like Spotlight Search in System Settings like ~/Library that results in applications that normally wouldn't show up in "Open With" showing up.

Thanks, I have accepted your answer and I will open a bug issue against Edge.

@Qiulang邱朗 No problem. Glad that I could help! :)
